# Get to array in react state

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am using redux for state management on react-native and I am a total rookie, be warned ;)

I am converting my static data to using the product state instead of an array.

**This is my static product array which will later be fetched from an API.**

```
    const products = [
       {id: 1, title: 'Apple Pie'},
    ];
```

**On app load I set the state like this:**

```
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(allActions.productActions.setProducts(products))
    },[]);
```

**On my view I call the getItem function, which works fine with the static array**

```
    function getItem(itemId) {
      let obj = products.filter(item => item.id === itemId);
      return obj[0];
    }
```

the function returns an undefined object error, because it expects the actual array and not the state object.

**The products state looks like that:**

```
 [{"products":[{"id":1,"title":"Apple Pie"}]}]
```

**out of that I need:**

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Apple Pie"}]
```

Comment: so on that first object you need  to call `[0].products` for examplke `stateObject[0].products`

Comment: It might be a better idea to use an object to represent your products where the keys are product IDs and the values are your products, rather than an array. For example `{ “1”: { title: “Apple Pie” } }`. This would allow you to get an item just by using `products[productID]` which is constant time, instead of linear time with `products.filter`.